# Is it possible to create an AWS lambda layer for C++ runtime?

Tags: c++, aws-lambda, aws-lambda-layers

We have a few c++ workloads in our organization that need to be migrated to the cloud, and we are trying to go serverless.
As a PoC, I am trying to create a sample lambda function that runs c++ code. This uses the [c++ runtime](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lambda-cpp).

I was able to create a zip file which packages a C++ hello world function, **along with** the C++ runtime by following this [AWS blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-the-c-lambda-runtime/).

I wanted to isolate the C++ runtime in a lambda layer for obvious advantages that a lambda layer provides. But I was not able to find any documentation that helps with this.

My question is: Is it possible to create a lambda layer for C++ runtime?
If so, how should my bootstrap file look like?

Any pointers on this would really help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to create a Lambda layer for the C++ runtime. Follow the link below to see how it's done!

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5377596/Working-with-AWS-Lambda-Cplusplus-Runtime-as-Lambd

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35695490)

Comment: Thanks a lot Peter! I will try this out. I would have to agree with @PrashantKumar though. Can you please provide a gist as an answer?